# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I m trying to list my buckets in my region, but it don't work

config :

```
[default]

region = eu-west-1
```

I have this error :

```
C:\Users\QXY9941>aws s3 ls --region=eu-west-1

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

My s3 in aws  :
[My s3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h22C.png)

Thanks

Comment: Is any file manager can access your point? I used S3 Browser to investigate any issues

Answer (score 0):

There might be few reasons behind it.

1.Missing credentials in the AWS profile if it is not configured already. Try adding
`aws_access_key_id`  and `aws_secret_access_key` to `~/.aws/credentials` file

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
aws_access_key_id = <your_access_key>
aws_secret_access_key = <your_secret_key>
```

2. Another issue could be the network access from your network to the cloud. Check whether your network can connect to the S3 endoints or not. This link might be helpful :
   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-could-not-connect-endpoint-url/

Comment: I configured my key :
[default]

aws_access_key_id = XXX

aws_secret_access_key = XXX

C:\Users\QXY9941>aws configure

AWS Access Key ID [****************ZWVL]:

AWS Secret Access Key [****************+IjK]:

Default region name [eu-west-1]:

Default output format [None]: